# Чтение файла в разных версиях Android API

Tags: android, api, android-scoped-storage

Есть отрывок кода, который открывает файл через файловый менеджер и считывает его:

```
public void loadCarMenu (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("text/*");
        //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode){
            case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    String pathFile = data.getData().getPath();
                    //File inputFile = new File (pathFile);
                    FileInputStream  fin = null;
                    try {
                        fin = new FileInputStream(pathFile);
                        byte [] bytes = new byte[fin.available()];
                        fin.read(bytes);
                        String info = new String(bytes);
                        textView.setText(info);
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex) {

                    }
                    finally {
                        try{
                            if(fin!=null)
                                fin.close();
                        }
                        catch(IOException ex){

                        }
                    }
                    //textView.setText(data.toString());
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Суть вопроса в том, что на API версии 29 данный файл не воспринимается, хотя путь до файла отображается верно.
Разрешения на чтение и запись в манифесте присутствуют:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: К верному ответу добавлю. Независимо от версии API, `data.getData()` не гарантирует что полученный Uri будет объектом файловой системы. Это может быть ссылкой на Drive или другое облачное хранилище.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добро пожаловать в [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage)

Суть состоит в том, что начиная с API 29 приложения имеют ограниченный доступ к внешнему хранилищу. Если вкратце доступ к внешним файлам на чтение дается только через `InputStream`, который можно получить приблизительно так:

```
Uri uri = intent.getData(); //Intent полученный через `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT/ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Указатель на `File` при этом получить невозможно. Аналогично можно и писать - через `OutputStream`

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо [Barmaley Red Star](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley-red-star) за ответ, реализовал таким образом, если кому понадобится:

```
public void openText(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("text/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
    }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.open_text);
                    InputStream is = null;
                    try {
                        is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[is.available()];
                        is.read(bytes);
                        String text = new String (bytes);
                        textView.setText(text.toString());
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    finally{

                        try{
                            if(is!=null)
                                is.close();
                        }
                        catch(IOException ex){

                            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Несколько замечаний к коду:
1) `data.getData().getPath()` - это не всегда работает, например в случае, если путь что-то типа `content://bla-bla/msf:15` :)
2) `new byte[is.available()]` - это опасная конструкция чреватая переполнением кучи

Comment: 1) Поправил:
String pathFile = data.getData().getPath(); File file = new File(pathFile); - лишнее, и вообще нигде дальше не используется, забыл убрать при проверке
2) на счет конструкции обдумаю варианты
Спасибо