Проблема доступа к некоторым файлам в директории "Download"
Попытка загрузить файлы:
private fun loadListFiles() {
        val f: File = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val listFiles = f.listFiles()
        adapter.listDocuments = listFiles.toMutableList()
    }

Данный код работает, но на Android 14 recycler отображает не все файлы (pdf, doc - не отображаются), отображаются только jpg, mp4, png. На Android 10 все норм

нет необходимых разрешений

@Style-7 А можно поконкретнее? В манифесте вроде есть все необходимые разрешения

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1165331/5648
